# Is there an Infura equivalent for BSC?

Tags: infura, bsc

I am new to infura and was wondering how people interact with other smart chains.

Is there an equivalent service like infura for the Binance Smart Chain? Or can you still use infura for BSC?

Comment: Their documentation mention some end points that can be used https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are looking for a fully managed third party RPC provider for BSC, you can use:

- [Quiknode](https://www.quiknode.io/bsc)
- [Ankr](https://docs.ankr.com/enteprise-solutions/binance-smart-chain)

If you want complete chain data, you can use their [snapshots](https://docs.binance.org/guides/node/snapshot.html)

Comment: note bsc testnet is not support in quicknode serivce.

Comment: It is supported now

Comment: BSC Testnet is now supported in QuikNode

Answer (score 3):

There are some RPC providers for Binance Smart Chain, BSC.

You can read [BSC docs for RPC](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html)

I think this will be the best curated (and official) list for RPC in BSC.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Moralis' speedyNodes => https://admin.moralis.io/speedyNodes

Answer (score -1):

The best RPC provider would be Omnia Protocol ➡️ https://omniatech.io/pages/dev/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/89051)