# Can binance trace one's IP address or some other private data?

Tags: decentralization, binance, vulnerability, anonymity

All the validators of the binance networks belong to Binance the company and as such as centralized, right?

In case something shady happens, such as a hack that has to do with a vulnerability in a smart contract, and when millions get stolen, can it be that all the validators get a command from someone on the top and try to trace an IP address of some who's created a certain smart contract or sent a certain transction? Thus trying to deanonymize a person.

Or even reverse a transaction?

I'm aware that Ethereum blockchain ins't anonymous. But Binance chains are, therefore, even less so.

Comment: Whether they will or won't, you still have to trust their policy, which could change. Even if a company says they won't do something, people don't want to have to trust them, that's why they choose decentralized systems.

Comment: Also a hacker can use [any RPC provider they wish](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97443/is-there-an-infura-equivalent-for-bsc). This makes it more difficult to track transactions, they'll also have to ask the RPC provider if they have any logs.

Comment: @DavidCallanan yeah, but my question isn't about that